# RTMP buffer/relay for network instability compensation

Tags: nginx, video-streaming, rtmp

Imagine scenario: Live RTMP broadcast must be conducted form location were it's possible that network problems will occur. There will be a second link (LTE) which can be considered "last resort" because it's not so reliable. Automatic link switching in place, but everything takes time. I thought that it would be possible to first broadcast to some kind of relay station with 1-2minutes buffer so in case of loosing connection it would keep it alive for some time until main location is reconnected to one of links. I've tried nginx-rtmp-module and playing with all kind of options but every time I disconnect source from network there is a hiccup on stream (I've tested it on youtube live stream). First time I try I get few seconds until stream freeze, but from second time it;s almost instant when OBS machine looses connection to internet. Client buffer length on nginx have almost no impact other than time I have to wait for stream to show on youtube.

my config:

```
rtmp {
    ping 10s;
    server {
        listen 1935;
        buflen 20s;
        chunk_size 4096;

        application live {
            idle_streams off;
            live on;
            record off;
            push rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/my_super_duper_key;
        }
    }
}
```

I would be very grateful for any help, maybe I should be using something different than nginx?

Comment: Have you considered using something other than RTMP?  There are a lot of choices, but probably the most off-the-shelf method would be to use HLS.  This would allow you to repeat failed segment uploads if you wanted, and also dynamically shift bitrate on the source end if you needed to.  On your buffering proxy of sorts, it would receive the HLS segments, and could still read them and remux to FLV to send over RTMP to YouTube or wherever.

Comment: That's really good idea. Great thanks. However I'm not sure broadcasting software that's available to us on this event supports HLS. But I will definitely check

Comment: You could always set something up where there's a local RTMP "server" which your broadcasting software connects to.  This local server then buffers data, sends it off to the remote whenever/however it can, and then the remote buffers and then replays the stream in realtime off to YouTube.  I don't know of any off-the-shelf software that does this, but you could utilize FFmpeg and Node.js (etc.) to do it.  If you don't want to DIY and would rather hire someone to build it, please e-mail me at brad@audiopump.co.